# Cmake Protobuf generate headers only

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

In a project generating protobuf files with cmake, is it possible to separate the headers from the source files with the `protobuf_generate` command?

Currently used is the following:

```
protobuf_generate(
  TARGET
    my_target
  LANGUAGE
    cpp
  GENERATE_EXTENSIONS
    .pb.h
  PROTOC_OUT_DIR
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen/src
  PROTOS
    ${PROTO_SOURCES}
)
protobuf_generate(
  TARGET
    my_target
  LANGUAGE
    cpp
  GENERATE_EXTENSIONS
    .pb.cc
  PROTOC_OUT_DIR
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen
  PROTOS
    ${PROTO_SOURCES}
)
```

Which generates both cc and h files into both directories. Is there a way to only generate the headers with the protobuf cmake commands, or the only way to solve it is to
move the generated files into a different folder?

Comment: After digging through the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/install.html#installing-targets), I found that  the following can be used to selet the header files only: `install( DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen DESTINATION include/gen FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
`  This doesn't filter protobuf, but only copies the header files in case `make install`

Comment: "Is there a way to only generate the headers with the protobuf cmake commands" - There is no such way. [Implementation](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake#L141) of `protobuf_generate` executes `protoc` utility. Being used for C++ language, this utility generates a header and a source files **at once**. It is impossible to execute this utility for generate only a header.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you that is good to know! Doesn't matter anyway, because with the install command it is possible to filter out the files. If you'd write your comment as an answer I'd gladly accept it.